# What is the minimum weight a bike can be and still be safe?

Tags: road-bike

For example, could you ride a 1 pound bike and still be safe or what? I want to know the minimum weight a bike can be and still be safe to ride.

Comment: There is straight answer. A road bike put together professionally can be durable and weigh far less than the limit of 6.8 kg, on the other hand poorly weight saving drillings can turn any bike into disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: For clarity that's the *Union Cycliste Internationale* (UCI) lower weight limit for racing bikes.

Comment: A 1 pound bike isn't realistic anyway and then there is another factor, the weight of the rider. If you put a 100kg rider on a 5.8kg bike (those exist) the thing would probably collapse. Most bicycles and their load-carrying components, especially wheels, seat-post, saddle, bars and pedals have never to exceed weight limits.

Comment: Probably the hardest parts to reduce weight on are the tires.

Answer (score 4):

The question can't be answered in its current form, because you don't specify what kind of bicycle under what conditions.

For example, a track racing bike designed to be ridden on a velodrome has a single gear, no derailleurs, no brakes; in fact no extraneous components at all. It does not have to be designed for years of use nor to withstand anything less than a perfectly flat road surface.

A single speed bike needs no derailleur or cassette but does have brakes and needs to be build to withstand rough road surfaces.  A standard road racing style bike needs all that plus derailleurs, cassette etc. Mountain bikes need to be built to handle rougher surfaces and impacts. You get the idea.

Additionally, the factor that limits the mass of a bike is not 'safety', i.e., can they be ridden without breaking underneath the rider, it's strength and stiffness to transmit power efficiently and immediately. This applies to the frame, wheels, cranks, handlebars and other components.

If you want an idea about how light a 'practical' multi-geared road racing bike can get, [it's under 5kgs](http://road.cc/content/feature/211663-6-lightest-road-bikes-%E2%80%94-bike-makers-challenge-scales-exotic-materials).